# Calculate time differences by accumulating these differences when the measured value is zero

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the following dataframe with id numbers, dates-times of readings and a value at each reading.

```
df <- data.frame(encounterId = c(1026, 1026, 1026, 1026, 1026, 1026, 1026, 1026, 1026, 1026, 1026, 1026),
chartTime = c("2015-09-16 14:11:00 CEST", "2015-09-16 14:13:00 CEST", "2015-09-16 15:00:00 CEST", "2015-09-16 15:08:00 CEST", "2015-09-16 16:00:00 CEST", "2015-09-16 16:22:00 CEST", "2015-09-16 17:00:00 CEST", "2015-09-16 17:41:00 CEST", "2015-09-16 18:00:00 CEST", "2015-09-16 18:01:00 CEST", "2015-09-16 19:00:00 CEST", "2015-09-16 19:53:00 CEST"),
value = c(2.0, 2.0, 0.0, 2.0, 2.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0))
```

I would like to calculate the time difference between each line.

So I wrote :

```
df <- df %>%
  group_by(encounterId) %>%
  mutate(time_diff = as.numeric(difftime(lead(chartTime), chartTime), units = 'mins'))
```

However, when several values are zero, I want to get the cumulative value of the time difference (for exemple for the first zero of the serie, and NA value for the following zeros).

The expected results would be :

| encounterId | chartTime | value | time_diff |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1026 | 2015-09-16 14:11:00 CEST | 2 | 2 |
| 1026 | 2015-09-16 14:13:00 CEST | 2 | 47 |
| 1026 | 2015-09-16 15:00:00 CEST | 0 | 8 |
| 1026 | 2015-09-16 15:08:00 CEST | 2 | 52 |
| 1026 | 2015-09-16 16:00:00 CEST | 2 | 22 |
| 1026 | 2015-09-16 16:22:00 CEST | 0 | 99 |
| 1026 | 2015-09-16 17:00:00 CEST | 0 | NA |
| 1026 | 2015-09-16 17:41:00 CEST | 0 | NA |
| 1026 | 2015-09-16 18:00:00 CEST | 0 | NA |
| 1026 | 2015-09-16 18:01:00 CEST | 2 | 59 |
| 1026 | 2015-09-16 19:00:00 CEST | 2 | 53 |
| 1026 | 2015-09-16 19:53:00 CEST | 2 |  |

I have tried several methods but have not find the solution. Obvioulsy I would rather not use a loop (for i in 1:nrow()) because my dataframe has more than one billion rows and it would be time expansive !

I would like to thank the community for their help in this matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can remove duplicated 0 first, calculated time_diff and then append the duplicated 0.

```
library(dplyr)

df2 <- df %>% 
  mutate(id = consecutive_id(value)) 

df2[df2$value!=0 | !duplicated(df2$id),]%>%
  group_by(encounterId) %>%
  mutate(time_diff = as.numeric(difftime(lead(chartTime), chartTime), units = 'mins')) %>%
  bind_rows(df2[df2$value==0 & duplicated(df2$id),]) %>% 
  arrange(encounterId, chartTime) %>%
  select(-id) %>%
  ungroup()

# A tibble: 12 × 4
   encounterId chartTime                value time_diff
         <dbl> <chr>                    <dbl>     <dbl>
 1        1026 2015-09-16 14:11:00 CEST     2         2
 2        1026 2015-09-16 14:13:00 CEST     2        47
 3        1026 2015-09-16 15:00:00 CEST     0         8
 4        1026 2015-09-16 15:08:00 CEST     2        52
 5        1026 2015-09-16 16:00:00 CEST     2        22
 6        1026 2015-09-16 16:22:00 CEST     0        99
 7        1026 2015-09-16 17:00:00 CEST     0        NA
 8        1026 2015-09-16 17:41:00 CEST     0        NA
 9        1026 2015-09-16 18:00:00 CEST     0        NA
10        1026 2015-09-16 18:01:00 CEST     2        59
11        1026 2015-09-16 19:00:00 CEST     2        53
12        1026 2015-09-16 19:53:00 CEST     2        NA
```