# Calculate time differences by accumulating these differences when the measured value is zero with groups

Tags: r, tidyverse

Few months latter the previous question ([Calculate time differences by accumulating these differences when the measured value is zero](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75987461/10211453)), the script doesn't work anymore with new datas!

If I copy paste the previous code, it works well. In the same script, when I use datas from another dataframe with the same colnames, the same column types (encounterId: num, chartTime: chr, value : num), it doesn't work... perhaps because the zeros are at the end of an encounter?

The df:

| encounterId | chartTime | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1026 | 2015-10-01 01:00:00 | 1.8 |
| 1026 | 2015-10-01 01:39:00 | 0 |
| 1026 | 2015-10-01 01:41:00 | 1.8 |
| 1026 | 2015-10-01 02:00:00 | 1.8 |
| 1026 | 2015-10-01 03:00:00 | 1.8 |
| 1026 | 2015-10-01 04:00:00 | 1.8 |
| 1026 | 2015-10-01 05:00:00 | 1.8 |
| 1026 | 2015-10-01 06:00:00 | 1.8 |
| 1026 | 2015-10-01 07:00:00 | 1.8 |
| 1026 | 2015-10-01 08:00:00 | 1.8 |
| 1026 | 2015-10-01 08:12:00 | 0 |
| 1026 | 2015-10-01 08:13:00 | 0 |
| 1026 | 2015-10-01 08:29:00 | 0 |
| 1026 | 2015-10-01 12:12:00 | 0 |
| 7772 | 2019-08-15 01:05:00 | 1.2 |
| 7772 | 2019-08-15 02:00:00 | 1.2 |
| 7772 | 2019-08-15 03:00:00 | 1.2 |
| 7772 | 2019-08-15 04:00:00 | 1.2 |
| 7772 | 2019-08-15 05:00:00 | 1.2 |
| 7772 | 2019-08-15 06:00:00 | 1.2 |
| 7772 | 2019-08-15 07:00:00 | 1.2 |

The results:

| encounterId | chartTime | value | time_diff |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1026 | 2015-10-01 01:00:00 | 1.8 | 39 |
| 1026 | 2015-10-01 01:39:00 | 0 | 2 |
| 1026 | 2015-10-01 01:41:00 | 1.8 | 19 |
| 1026 | 2015-10-01 02:00:00 | 1.8 | 60 |
| 1026 | 2015-10-01 03:00:00 | 1.8 | 60 |
| 1026 | 2015-10-01 04:00:00 | 1.8 | 60 |
| 1026 | 2015-10-01 05:00:00 | 1.8 | 60 |
| 1026 | 2015-10-01 06:00:00 | 1.8 | 60 |
| 1026 | 2015-10-01 07:00:00 | 1.8 | 60 |
| 1026 | 2015-10-01 08:00:00 | 1.8 | 12 |
| 1026 | 2015-10-01 08:12:00 | 0 | NA |
| 1026 | 2015-10-01 08:13:00 | 0 | NA |
| 1026 | 2015-10-01 08:29:00 | 0 | NA |
| 1026 | 2015-10-01 12:12:00 | 0 | NA |
| 7772 | 2019-08-15 01:05:00 | 1.2 | 55 |
| 7772 | 2019-08-15 02:00:00 | 1.2 | 60 |
| 7772 | 2019-08-15 03:00:00 | 1.2 | 60 |
| 7772 | 2019-08-15 04:00:00 | 1.2 | 60 |
| 7772 | 2019-08-15 05:00:00 | 1.2 | 60 |
| 7772 | 2019-08-15 06:00:00 | 1.2 | 60 |
| 7772 | 2019-08-15 07:00:00 | 1.2 | NA |

Many thanks for you help

I am working with R Studio 2023.03.1, dplyr 1.1.4

Comment: `difftime` is not documented as handling character arguments but `as.difftime` is. I can’t determine if this is related to your problems since you are not offering a sufficiently unambiguous version of your data. Review how to use `dput` for that purpose in one of the many descriptions of the process available on SO.